# How to Automate Oracle forms using Jcob library

Tags: oracleforms

Hi i am trying to automate oracle forms using jcob library.can any one tell me How to Automate Oracle forms using Jcob library

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you narrowed it down to a specific problem? Have a go first before asking questions here

Answer (score 0):

You probably ment Jacob library for using COM components from Java. You can use it, but you have to sign its jar with trusted certificate.

Or simply use oracle Webutil library. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/howto-ole-090332.html